# post request gives 403 forbidden django ajax

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I've a register form and a function to post the values to django via ajax, but for some reasons, the post request says `403 forbidden` but the get request does the job.

I want to use post request in this functionality but it doesn't seem to work, tried putting `{% csrf_form %}` too within the template, but still it says `403 Forbidden`. Any sugestion?

**Views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View

class signUp(View):
    def post(self, request):
        return HttpResponse(" POST method  successfull !!")
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('insert/', views.signUp.as_view()),
```

**HTML Form:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
<title> Register </title>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<div class="row breadcrumb_nav">

    <div class="col-md-1" ></div>
    <div class="col-md-10" style="margin-bottom: 35px;">
       <!-- START col-md-12 Section -->
       <ol class="breadcrumb  nm" >
          <li><a href="login.php"> Home </a></li>
          <li class="active"> Register </li>
       </ol>
       <div id="quickViewPage_error_container">
          <div id="animated_image"></div>
          <div id="results_container"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <!--end of col-md-12 -->
    <div class="col-md-1" ></div>

</div> <!-- end of row -->


<!--start of row -->
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-1" ></div>
   <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- START Right Section -->
      <div class="main_shadow panel panel-default"> <!-- START OF panel panel-default-->
         <div class="panel-body panel-body-padding"> <!-- -START OF PANE -->
            <div class="modal-header">
               <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> Register </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="panel-body"> <!-- -START OF PANE -->
                  <form id="signup_form" name="signup_form" method="post">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <label class="control-label"> eMail  <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                              <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <label class="control-label">Password <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                              <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" data-parsley-trigger="change"  required>
                           </div>
                        </div>

                     </div>
                     <input type="hidden" name="register_new_user" id="register_new_user" value="register_new_user">

                     <input type="submit" name="register_btn" id="register_btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" style="float:left;padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px;margin-right: 25px;">

                     <a href="/register">
                         <input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Register Now" style="float:left;padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px;">
                     </a>

                  </form> <!--end of Login_Management -->
               </div> <!-- END OF panel-body -->
            </div>
         </div> <!-- END OF panel-body -->
      </div> <!--/ End of  Form  layout -->
   </div> <!-- END OF Right Section -->
   <div class="col-md-1" ></div>
</div>
<!-- end of row -->

enter code here
{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}

<script>
$('#register_btn').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$.post('/insert/', '&register_new_user=register_new_user' + 
'&csrftoken={{ csrf_token }}' , function(response) {
    $('#results_container').html(response);
});

});
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In your urls.py file, do you write `from views import signUp` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the data in the path like this:

```
$.post('/insert/', '&register_new_user=register_new_user' + 
'&csrftoken={{ csrf_token }}' , function(response) {
    $('#results_container').html(response);
});
```

Try sending the data in the body:

```
$.post( '/insert/', { register_new_user: "register_new_user", csrftoken: "your_token_here" } );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :)) but renaming csrftoken to csrfmiddlewaretoken did the job